# ¿Cuál es el origen de "la canina" como sinónimo de "calavera" o "esqueleto"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, españa

No puedo encontrar ahora mismo entradas en el CORDE, pero en algunas partes de Andalucía se usa la palabra "canina" para referirse al esqueleto humano, o a la calavera. Sé que al menos en Sevilla y en Málaga se usa, aunque el DLE [no recoja este significado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=79UjoUa). Sí que recoge otros como "propio de un perro" (de donde viene "un hambre canina"), "excremento de perro" (ya usado en el siglo XVI) o "canícula".

¿De dónde puede provenir este significado tan regional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque no aparezca en el diccionario, en el [Fichero General](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) sí que hay una ficha que hace referencia a este significado. Buscando el término "canina", [la ficha 73](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_I_PDF/CANINA/00000959.pdf) (PDF) dice:

> **Canina**.- Esqueleto. "La muerte canina".

Esta entrada corresponde a un libro publicado en 1973: "Vocabulario popular malagueño", escrito por Juan Cepas. Sobre el origen del término, la siguiente información está extraída de [este artículo](http://www.abc.es/sociedad/abci-canina-pavor-guasa-sevillana-201603231638_noticia.html) del ABC y de [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermandad_del_Santo_Entierro_(Sevilla)).

En la Semana Santa sevillana sale de procesión un paso al que el pueblo le dio el nombre de "La Canina". El paso representa el triunfo de la santa cruz sobre la muerte, simbolizado por un esqueleto meditabundo, sentado sobre un globo terráqueo, y junto a él un dragón abatido que representa al pecado. La talla original fue realizada en 1691, y en 1693 salió de procesión por primera vez, aterrorizando a los ciudadanos. Sin embargo, al poco tiempo la guasa de la gente se sobrepuso al temor, y Sevilla acabó bautizando al paso como "la Canina". Se dice que la primera expresión escrita de este nombre fue en 1797, aunque no he encontrado el texto.

El darle el nombre de "la Canina" no está claro, pero seguramente tuvo que ver con la acepción de "pasar un hambre canina", dado que aquí en Sevilla se suele usar "la canina" como sinónimo de hambre:

> Illo, vamos a comer que tengo una canina que no veas.

También se usa la expresión "estar canino" como sinónimo de estar en los huesos, o no tener dinero (lo uno lleva a lo otro). El caso es que lo que rodea al pasar hambre lleva el apelativo "canina", lo que hace muy plausible que este fuera el origen del mote del paso: la figura que siempre tiene hambre (ya sea por estar en los huesos o tal vez se refiera al hambre de almas que segar).

Un ejemplo de esta guasa es una saeta de Pepe Peregil que decía:

> Ay Canina cuánto te quiero
>   pero cómo te hace falta
>   un buen caldo del puchero

El caso es que, a partir de entonces, se viene denominando "canina" al esqueleto humano, o simplemente a las calaveras humanas.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión es una **alegoría** o **metonimia** (alguna de las dos o ambas). El caso es que se hace alusión al perro para representar la imagen de un esqueleto para hacer una **alegoría** (no pude resistir la repetición) a la propia muerte.

Un ejemplo de este tipo de usos lo encontramos en la corriente literaria de las calaveras mexicanas. Estas se comezaron a publicar a mediados del siglo XX inicialmente como una caricatura satírica de personajes reales o imaginarios (entre los que figuraban, muchas veces, personajes de política) y que, a manera que iba evolucionando se iba introduciendo en la codidianeidad mexicana hasta el punto de fundisrse con las tradiciones del día de muertos.

La relación que existe entre las calaveras mexicanas y la Canina que refiere el artículo que expones es que la muerte es vista como un personaje pensante capaz de decidir a quien elige como su próximo objetivo. Entonces, como es percibida como un enemigo omnipresente, no se nombra directamente para no invocarla.

El origen de este tipo de cambios es, sin duda, mas antiguo. En el Quijote se relaciona a la muerte con la palabra **canina** (no la nombra así sino que dice que tiene **"hambre canina"**). Pero Sancho intenta no nombrarla y le dice **descarnada** aunque después la nombra directamente.

> A buena fe, señor —respondió Sancho—, que no hay que fiar en la
>   **descarnada**, digo, en la muerte, la cual tan bien come cordero como carnero; y a nuestro cura he oído decir que con igual pie pisaba las
>   altas torres de los reyes como las humildes chozas de los pobres.
>   Tiene esta señora más de poder que de melindre; no es nada asquerosa:
>   de todo come y a todo hace, y de toda suerte de gentes, edades y
>   preeminencias hinche sus alforjas. No es segador que duerme las
>   siestas, que a todas horas siega, y corta así la seca como la verde
>   yerba; y no parece que masca, sino que engulle y traga cuanto se le
>   pone delante, porque tiene **hambre canina**, que nunca se harta; y aunque
>   no tiene barriga, da a entender que está hidrópica y sedienta de beber
>   solas las vidas de cuantos viven, como quien se bebe un jarro
>   de agua fría.

Ante todo esto, solo puedo inferir que culturalmente es recurrente el nombrar a la muerte (y a otros entes malignos) con nombres o frases que disminuyen su sentido catastrófico. Quizá, como he dicho, esto tiene un poco más con la cultura que con el idioma en si.

Comment: Interesante reflexión, pero creo que la expresión "hambre canina" no se refiere a la muerte, sino literalmente a tener un hambre propia de un perro. Hay una expresión que es "tener más hambre que un perrillo chico", por el ansia con la que suelen comer estos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la aclaración @Charlie. De hecho, en México decimos que tiene "hambre de perro" cuando alguien come con exceso o con ansia desmedida. Alguien podría incluso decir que la muerte es "canina" por su apetito voraz (aquí estoy de nuevo complicándolo todo). No pretendo conocer la idiosincrasia sevillana; solo quiero generalizar con un punto de vista a la mexicana que, creo que concordarás, no está completamente dislocado del de España.

Answer (score 0):

"Canina""Tengo un hambre canina"  el perro que no come "se queda en los huesos", de ahí la similitud entre canina y esqueleto.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!